# What is the complexity difference Breath First Search and Depth First search?

Tags: search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, theory

I can't seem to find a difference; I know one uses a queue and the other a stack but how does that effect the RunTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the BFS (Breath First Search) is `O(|V|+|E|)` and the complexity of the DFS (Deep First Search) is `O(|V|+|E|)`. So, theoretically, they will spent the same time to run.

PS: `|V|` is the number of vertices and `|E|` is the number of edges,

Comment: Different algorithm for different purposes. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).